# How to use environmental variables in Logstash 5.X?

Tags: logstash

We've just switched from 2.X to 5.X, and I'm trying to find out how to use environmental variables in the pipeline configuration files.

In 2.X, the following worked:

```
export HOSTNAME
```

Then start Logstash with the `--allow-env` command line flag. The pipeline configuration file looked like this:

```
filter {
       mutate {
              add_field => { "some_field" => "${HOSTNAME}"}
       }
}
```

The documentation says that the `--allow-env` flag is not required anymore.

I've tried to replace `mutate` with the `environment` filter, but with no luck.

I've tried to edit the `startup.options` file. Added `HOSTNAME` as a usual environment variable, and added it between the `read-EOM` part, but without any positive results.

What seems to be working now if I add the following part to the `/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash.lib.sh` file, but I'm nut sure if I'm supposed to edit that.

```
HOSTNAME="the-name-of-the-host"
export HOSTNAME
```

So my question is: what have I overlooked? What is the proper way to allow the usage of enviromental variables in Logstash's pipeline configuration files?

**Note:**

Like Alcanzar described, this works if I run Logstash manually. However we would like to run it with `systemctl`, so it should be automatically started by the daemon on startup. In 2.X, it worked fine with the `/etc/init.d/logstash` file, but as the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.x/config-setting-files.html) describes, that is no more. The files I'm supposed to edit are: `/etc/logstash/startup.options` and `/etc/logstash/logstash.yml`.

Answer (score 2):

The environment variables clearly work if starting manually:

With a test.conf of this:

```
input {
    stdin { codec => "json" }
}
filter {
    mutate {
        add_field => {
            "hostname" => "${HOSTNAME}"
        }
    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => "rubydebug" }
}
```

We can run a test and verify it:

```
% export HOSTNAME="abc1234" 
% echo '{"a":1}' | bin/logstash -f test.conf
Sending Logstash's logs to /Users/xxxxxx/logstash-5.1.1/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2017-02-16T09:04:33,442][INFO ][logstash.inputs.stdin    ] Automatically switching from json to json_lines codec {:plugin=>"stdin"}
[2017-02-16T09:04:33,454][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>1000}
[2017-02-16T09:04:33,457][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline main started
[2017-02-16T09:04:33,492][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
{
             "a" => 1,
      "hostname" => "abc1234",
    "@timestamp" => 2017-02-16T15:04:33.497Z,
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "XXXXXX.local",
          "tags" => []
}
[2017-02-16T09:04:36,472][WARN ][logstash.agent           ] stopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
```

So the real question is why isn't it working in your scenario.  If you are using some sort of `/etc/init.d` script to start logstash, then you can add to `/etc/sysconfig/logstash` a line like `export HOSTNAME="whatever"`

Comment: Yes, you are completely right on this. I've forgot to mention that we would like to run it with the systemctl command. The documentation mentions the `/etc/logstash/startup.options` file and the `/etc/logstash/logstash.yml` so I added the exact line of code you've mentioned there before, but without any luck.

Comment: I think maybe this will tell you how to setup environment variables for systemd - http://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service - i don't use systemd, but the info looks solid

Comment: Unlike built-in fields which are accessed using '%', environment variables are accessed via '$'. For example: `output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "%{+YYYY.MM.dd}-%{+HH.mm}_${HOSTNAME}"
  }
}
`

Answer (score 1):

we had the same issue with logstash 5. The best way (that we found) is to add the env vars in /etc/systemd/system/logstash.service.d/override.conf and in there have

```
   [Service]
   Environment="HOSTNAME=the-name-of-the-host"
```